# Ignored an update to unaccepted module

Tags: javascript, webpack, webpack-dev-server, webpack-hmr

The console outputs `Ignored an update to unaccepted module` error, how to fix it?

```
log.js:25 Ignored an update to unaccepted module ./src/print.js -> 1
log.js:25 [HMR] The following modules couldn't be hot updated: (They would need a full reload!)
log.js:25 [HMR]  - ./src/print.js
```

the whole console message is:

```
log.js:23 [HMR] Waiting for update signal from WDS...
log.js:23 [HMR] Waiting for update signal from WDS...
client?cd17:64 [WDS] Hot Module Replacement enabled.
client?cd17:64 [WDS] Hot Module Replacement enabled.
client?cd17:67 [WDS] App updated. Recompiling...
client?cd17:67 [WDS] App updated. Recompiling...
client?cd17:67 [WDS] App updated. Recompiling...
client?cd17:67 [WDS] App updated. Recompiling...
client?cd17:193 [WDS] App hot update...
log.js:23 [HMR] Checking for updates on the server...
client?cd17:193 [WDS] App hot update...
log.js:23 [HMR] Checking for updates on the server...
log.js:25 Ignored an update to unaccepted module ./src/print.js -> 1
./node_modules/webpack/hot/log.js.module.exports @ log.js:25
onUnaccepted @ only-dev-server.js:25
hotApply @ bootstrap e5893b5…:437
(anonymous) @ only-dev-server.js:20
log.js:25 [HMR] The following modules couldn't be hot updated: (They would need a full reload!)
./node_modules/webpack/hot/log.js.module.exports @ log.js:25
./node_modules/webpack/hot/log-apply-result.js.module.exports @ log-apply-result.js:12
(anonymous) @ only-dev-server.js:39
log.js:25 [HMR]  - ./src/print.js
./node_modules/webpack/hot/log.js.module.exports @ log.js:25
(anonymous) @ log-apply-result.js:14
./node_modules/webpack/hot/log-apply-result.js.module.exports @ log-apply-result.js:13
(anonymous) @ only-dev-server.js:39
log.js:23 [HMR] Nothing hot updated.
log.js:23 [HMR] App is up to date.
index.js:8 Accepting the updated printMe module!
log.js:23 [HMR] Updated modules:
log.js:23 [HMR]  - ./src/print.js
log.js:23 [HMR] App is up to date.
```

The following is my code:

**webpack.config.js:**

```
const path = require('path');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const CleanWebpackPlugin = require('clean-webpack-plugin');
const webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
  devtool: 'inline-source-map',
  devServer: {
    contentBase: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    hotOnly: true,
  },
  entry: {
    app: './src/index.js',
    print: './src/print.js'
  },
  output: {
    filename: '[name].bundle.js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
  },
  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      title: 'Hot Module Replacement',
      filename: 'index.html',
    }),
    new CleanWebpackPlugin(['dist']),
    new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
    new webpack.NamedModulesPlugin(),
  ],
};
```

**./src/index.js:**

```
import _ from 'lodash';
import printMe from './print.js';

if(module.hot) {
  module.hot.accept('./print.js', function() {
    console.log('Accepting the updated printMe module!');

    document.body.removeChild(element);
    element = component();
    document.body.appendChild(element);
  });
}

let element = component();

function component() {
  const element = document.createElement('div');
  const btn = document.createElement('button');

  element.innerHTML = _.join(['Hell', 'webpack'], ' ');

  btn.innerHTML = 'Click me and check the console!';
  btn.onclick = printMe;

  element.appendChild(btn);

  return element;
}

document.body.appendChild(element);
```

**./src/print.js:**

```
export default function printMe() {
  //console.log('I get called from print.js!');
  console.log('Updating print.js...')
}
```

**package.json:**

```
{
  "name": "webpack-demo",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "webpack",
    "start": "webpack-dev-server --open"
  },
  "keywords": [
    "webpack",
    "demo"
  ],
  "author": "",
  "license": "MIT",
  "dependencies": {
    "lodash": "^4.17.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "clean-webpack-plugin": "^0.1.16",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^2.29.0",
    "webpack": "^3.4.1",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^2.6.1"
  }
}
```

other environment:

- node v7.4.0
- npm 4.0.5
- macOS Sierra 10.12
- Chrome v59.0.3071.115

please give me help.

Answer (score 2):

After debugging and testing, I think I know the answer.

Webpack-dev-server creates a client side script for every entry.

When I don't write any HMR interface, console outputs like this:

[image]

It seems like for the `app(./src/index.js)` client side script, `index.js` will accept the change of its dependency - `print.js`.

But for the `print(./src/print.js)` client side script, nothing will accept the change of its dependency - `print.js`.

So, only write a HMR interface in `index.js` don't work to the second situation and it throws `Ignored an update to unaccepted module` error.

Answer (score -1):

Removing print.js from entry prop of webpack configuration should solve this issue.